# Help identifying winged, moth-like creature

Tags: species-identification

I noticed this moth (?) on my sofa yesterday. It matched the color of the sofa, so it was pretty hard to see. It's about an inch long, with a yellow body and light brown wings. I think it's a [T. bisselliella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tineola_bisselliella). I'm from Kerala, South India.

[image: The moth I saw]

The wings:

[image]

Comment: This is not a Clothing moth, they are not so yellow and are much smaller, about 7-10 mm (1/3 inch). Please add a picture of the wings if possible, and rhe location it was found, that will make it easier to identify.

Comment: Try bugguide.net they are really good at this.

Comment: @futurebird We're really good at this too. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite certain that this is an [owlet moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noctuoidea?wprov=sfla1) that belongs to the species *[Asota caricae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asota_caricae?wprov=sfla1)*. It has the nickname "Tiger Moth", and is commonly found in the tropics of India.

I would like to note though that your first picture is somewhat misleading, just from where the flash washes the color so much. Because of this, I decided to more heavily rely on the second image than the first, which exhibits orange instead of yellow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is it, but the eyes weren't this blue and the legs were pretty different.

Comment: @AravindSuresh I'm gald to hear it :) Regarding the eye color, I believe the specific camera used changed the purple to a blue. See [here](https://www.photo.net/discuss/threads/why-does-purple-show-up-as-blue-in-the-photo.430267/) for a discussion of this effect. As for the legs, I think they look fairly similar.. can you tell me what you think looks different between the two? Just trying to refine my identification process. Thanks :)

Comment: The legs were not this gray, and not this big. Almost not this scary. But this is it anyway, I think the one I saw was younger than the one in the photo.